# EConnect not inserting a customers credit limit in GP

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, econnect

I have an application that uses EConnect to import information into GP. When I import customers using the taUpdateCreateCustomerRcd node I want to include a credit limit.

Here is the code I am using to insert the credit limit:

```
customer.CRLMTTYP = 2;
customer.CRLMTAMT = 1000;
```

For some reason the credit limit doesnt get imported for the customer. Any ideas what I am missing for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else that comes across this issue I figured out my problem. When you specify a credit limit type and amount you need to include the following:

```
customer.CRLMTTYPSpecified = true;
customer.CRLMTAMTSpecified = true;
```

Same goes for credit limit percentage.